# Why is $C=\{x\in l^2:|x_n|\leq 2^{-n},n=1,2,3,\dots\}$ compact?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

Why is $C=\{x\in l^2:|x_n|\leq 2^{-n},n=1,2,3,\dots\}$ compact?

I tried to show that $C$ is totally bounded and closed.

I showed that is closed but I don't know how to show that is totally bounded.

It's very simple to show that $C$ is bounded:

If $0$ is the zero sequence, there is an upper bound on $d(0,x)$ for all $x\in C$: $(\sum_{n\geq1}2^{-n})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the max for the distance $||\centerdot||_{l^2}$.

But I think that the unit ball is not totally bounded in $l^2$ and so the fact that C is bounded it's not usefull to show that is tottaly bounded. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried showing $C$ is totally bounded and closed?

Comment: I showed that is closed but how can I show that is totally bounded?

Comment: If $0$ is the zero sequence, is there an upper bound on $d(0,x)$ for all $x \in C$?

Comment: yes, I think that is 1 and it is also a maximum or is not?

Comment: Maybe to be more precise, is $(\sum_{n\geq1}(2^{-2n}))^{\frac{1}{2}}$ the max for the distance in $l^2$?

Comment: I have another question: we have showed that C is bounded not totally bounded. Is the two notion equivalent in $l^2$?

Comment: I checked and the unit ball is not totally bounded in $l^2$.

Comment: Related post at Ask a Topologist: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2013&task=show_msg&msg=3853

Answer (score 3):

So you have a set of the form
$$C=\{x\in\ell_2; |x_n|\le a_n\}$$
where $a_n$ is a series of positive real numbers such that $\sum a_n^2<+\infty$.
You want to show that this space is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space).

Let $\varepsilon>0$. We want to show that there exist finitely many points in $C$ such that each point of $C$ is within the distance $\varepsilon$ from some of these points.

Let $n_0$ be such that 
$$\sum_{k>n_0} a_n^2 < \frac\varepsilon2.$$

Now let us concentrate for a while on sequences in $C$ such that $x_n=0$ for $n>n_0$. This means that we are looking essentially on $\mathbb K^{n_0}$ (where $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$, depending on which field you are working with).
$$D=\{x\in C; n>n_0 \Rightarrow x_n=0\}$$
Can you show that there are finitely many points $x_1,\dots,x_k$ in $D$ such that for each $x\in D$ the distance $\|x-x_k\|<\varepsilon/2$ for some $k$? Can you show that the same $k$ gives
$$\|x-x_k\|<\varepsilon$$
for any $x\in C$?

---

The same problem as in your question appears in the book Banach Space Theory by Marián Fabian, Petr Habala, Petr Hájek, Vicente Montesinos, Václav Zizler as
[Exercise 1.15](https://books.google.sk/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA42). It is also mentioned there that this space is called [Hilbert cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube). (And once you know the name of this space, you can find [many other sources](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=l2+compact+%22hilbert+cube%22), where the same or similar problem appears.)

And a very similar problem appeared in Ask a Topologist forum: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2013&task=show_msg&msg=3853

Comment: I can proceed like that:

Let be $\epsilon>0$, we choose $k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{1}{k}<\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{n_0}}$ (I put the square root because we are using the distance in $l^2$). Now we can take the following set: $N=\{x\in\mathbb{N}^{n_0}: \frac{x}{k}=(\frac{x_1}{k},\dots,\frac{x_{n_0}}{k})\in D\}$ that is a finte set.

Now if we take an element in D, will exist an element in N such that the distance in $l^2$ from the two elements is lower then $\epsilon$.

This argoument shows that D is totally bounded.

Am I right?

Comment: @JacopoBorga Yes, any element of $D$ is within the distance $\varepsilon$ of an element of your set $N$ and this would show that $D$ si totally bounded. However, we want to prove that $C$ is totally bounded. So you should check whether every element of $C$ is $\varepsilon$-close to an element of $n$. (Which is why I user $\varepsilon/2$. Or you can use $\frac1k<\sqrt{\frac\varepsilon{2n_0}}$ in your definition of $N$.

Comment: BTW now I see that your definition of $N$ is a bit unclear. You should say what is $x_1,\dots,x_{n_0}$. (And perhaps simpler approach then trying to write $N$ down explicitly could be using compactness of $D$. We know that closed bounded subset of $\mathbb R^{n_0}$ is compact.)

Comment: Maybe you wanted to take all elements from $D$ of the form $(j_1/k,\dots,j_{n_0}/k)$ where $j_i$'s are integers? (The way you defined $N$ you do not get a finite set.)

Comment: Yes, when I write $x\in \mathbb{N}^{n_0}$, my intention was to say that the $x_i$'s were integers. Maybe $x\in \mathbb{Z}^{n_0}$ is more clear.

Comment: Want do you mean when you say that I can use compactness of $D$? Do you want to use that a bounded set is totally bounded set in a finite dimensional space?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. $D$ can be be considered as a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n_0}$, which is finite dimensional. (And I completely overlooked that in the definition of $N$ you had $\mathbb N$ rather than $\mathbb R$. So now it seems clearer to me. I agree that we in fact need $\mathbb Z$ there.)

Comment: A last question: I'm new in the forum and I don't know if I had to write now a complete solution. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I do not think that there is general rule about it saying what you *should* do. You can find some discussion about this on meta, for example, if you browse the questions tagged [meta-tag:self-answer] or [meta-tag:hint]. (For example, [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16486) is to some extent related.) My personal opinion is that you should post your solution as an answer if either of the following is true: 1) You think that your answer might be useful for other users which come here with the same question. (For example, if the gaps in the answer posted so far are too big and ...

Comment: ... you think it would be good to make a post filling all the gaps.) 2) You think that it might be useful for you to. Firstly as an exercise in writing proofs. And secondly since posting your proof here gives you a chance that other users who see it might let you know if it contains some inaccuracies, mistakes, non-standard notation, etc.

Comment: I wrote the complete solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with a metric space. So compactness sequential compactness are equivalent. If you have a sequence in your set, then each coordinate of that sequence is a bounded sequence and, hence, you can use Cantor diagonalization to obtain a subsequence that converges in each coordinate. Then the uniform bound that you have allows you to use dominated converges in order to conclude that the subsequence converges in the norm of the space (or you can do it directly without dominated convergence.)

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution:

$$C=\{x\in l^2:|x\centerdot e_n|\leq 2^{-n}, n=1,2,3,\dots\}$$

We want to prove that C is closed and totally bounded.

C is CLOSED: if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of elements in C and $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $l^2$, then $x_m\centerdot e_n\rightarrow x\centerdot e_n$, then $|x\centerdot e_n|\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

C is TOTALLY BOUNDED: We know that $\sum_{n\geq 1}(2^{-n})^2<+\infty$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$. We want to show that there exist finitely many points in $C$ such that each point of $C$ is within the distance $\varepsilon$ from some of these points.

Let $n_{\varepsilon}$ be such that $\sum_{k>n_{\varepsilon}}(2^{-n})^2<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$

Now let's focus on the sequences of $l^2$ s.t. if $n>n_{\varepsilon}$ then $x\centerdot e_n=0$:

$$D=\{x\in C :x\centerdot e_n=0, n>n_{\varepsilon}\}$$

so D is isomorphic to

$$D'=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n_\varepsilon}:|x\centerdot e_n|\leq2^{-n},n=1,\dots,n_{\varepsilon}\}$$

$D'$ is a closed and bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^{n_{\varepsilon}}$ so it is compact, and so totally bounded.
Then exists a set $N'=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ s.t. $N'\subset D'$, $|N'|<+\infty$ and for every $x\in D'$, exists $x_i\in N'$ s.t.

$$||x-x_i||^2_2=\sum_{n=1}^{n_\varepsilon}|(x-x_i)\centerdot e_n|^2<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
We now extend the set $N'$ to a subset $N$ of $C$

$$N=\{x\in C:\exists i | (x\centerdot e_n)=(x_i\centerdot e_n)\forall n=1,\dots,n_{n_\varepsilon},(x\centerdot e_n)=0\forall n>n_\varepsilon\}$$

Now it's easy to prove than $N$ is the set that checking the totally boundness of C:

1)$|N|<\infty$ and so we put $N=\{x'_1,\dots,x'_n\}$;
2)let $x\in C$. Exists i s.t.
$$||x-x'_i||_2^2=\sum_{n=1}^{n_\varepsilon}|(x-x'_i)\centerdot e_n|^2+\sum_{n>n_\varepsilon}|(x-x'_i)\centerdot e_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.$$